# Make a print screen of a web page and download image

Tags: javascript, printing, screen

i'm looking for a script that would take a print screen of a web page and download image to clients computer. the point is that its really user friendly, because user doesn't have to push the button (print screen) and paste it to some image editor program. Is this even possible?

thank you very much for your help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its not possible with JavaScript to make a screenshot of the actual site.
What you could do is useing a service like http://www.thumbalizr.com/ or browsershots or whaterver. But it would not be instant and it would not reflect the actual content the the user has on the screen.

PS: thumbalizr has an API

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of plugins that you might consider if you use firefox - Fireshot for instance? I hope this helps